# JMeter Group HTTP Request Results by IP Address

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to use JMeter to load test a load balancer, however, I'd like to group the results by the underlying IP Address being used to send the actual request.

I've added a DNS Cache Manager so I can control the DNS caching of the request, but, the results are reported for the entire session. What I'm looking for is the numbers to be broken out (or grouped) by the underlying IP address being used to send each individual request on the thread.

Comment: Do you know the ip when you get the response?

Comment: I see in the logs of the run that a cache miss happened... but, I don’t know how to associate that IP with results

Comment: in the response headers can you see the ip or specific server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can know after response the IP , for example using Regular Expression Extractor or JDBC Post Processor, then save IP in variable name as `currentIP` and add to the Sampler also [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor]) which will change the label:

```
prev.setSampleLabel("SamplerName with IP: " + vars.get("currentIP"));
```

Each IP will create different label and therefore results will be grouped by IPs.

Comment: Thanks... let me do some fiddling!